# Cosa significa "eleganza sprezzata" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia del nuovo cognome* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> A una prima visione fui impressionata soprattutto da me stessa. Ero inquadrata due volte. La prima sul sagrato, accanto ad Antonio: mi vidi goffa, nervosa, il viso mangiato dagli occhiali; la seconda, seduta al tavolo con Nino, quasi non mi riconobbi: ridevo, muovevo mani e braccia con **eleganza sprezzata**, mi ravviavo i capelli, giocherellavo col braccialetto di mia madre, mi sembrai fine e bella.

Ho cercato il significato di "sprezzare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di "eleganza sprezzata" nel brano precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sembra significhi 'con eleganza **disinvolta**', e l'origine del termine la trovi direttamente su Wikipedia:

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprezzatura

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Non c'è problema!